# Send message and leave server on ready event if not whitelisted (Discord.JS + MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, discord.js, whitelist

I'm coding a whitelist system for my discord bot that, on ready event (and after a 3 seconds delay), checks if every server it is in has it's ID added to the whitelist database on MongoDB. If not, the bot sends an embed and leaves the server. I managed to get it working on the *guildCreate* event, but on *ready* event it performs the message and leave actions on every single server without filtering conditions, even though those are added to the list. I cannot figure out why. Also, I'm still new to JavaScript, so it could be just a minor mistake.

```
//VARIABLES
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const config = require('../../Files/Configuration/config.json');
const DB = require("../../Schemas/WhitelistDB");

//READY EVENT
module.exports = {
  name: "ready",
  once: false,
  async execute(client) {

//[ ... ]     <--- OTHER UNNECESSARY CODE IN BETWEEN

    setTimeout(function() {    // <--- 3 SECONDS DELAY

      client.guilds.cache.forEach(async (guild) => {    // <--- CHECK EVERY SERVER

        await DB.find({}).then(whitelistServers => {    // <--- CHECK MONGODB ID LIST

          if(!whitelistServers.includes(guild.id)) {
            const channel = guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_TEXT').random(1)[0];    // <--- SEND MESSAGE TO RANDOM TEXT CHANNEL (It is sending to every server, when it should be sending only to the not whitelisted ones)
              if(channel) {
                const WhitelistEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                WhitelistEmbed.setColor(config.colors.RED)
                WhitelistEmbed.setDescription(`${config.symbols.ERROR} ${config.messages.SERVER_NOT_WHITELISTED}`)
                channel.send({embeds: [WhitelistEmbed]});
              }
            client.guilds.cache.get(guild.id).leave();    // <--- LEAVE SERVER (It is leaving every server, when it should be leaving only the not whitelisted ones)
          } else { return }
        });

      });

    }, 1000 * 3);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution myself!**

Instead of finding the array of whitelisted ID's for each guild, find one at a time and instead of checking the content of the array, check if the array exists. This is the updated code:

```
//WHITELIST
setTimeout(function() {

  client.guilds.cache.forEach(async (guild) => {

    await DB.findOne({ GuildID: guild.id }).then(whitelistServers => {
      if(!whitelistServers) {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_TEXT').random(1)[0];
          if(channel) {
            const WhitelistEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            WhitelistEmbed.setColor(config.colors.RED)
            WhitelistEmbed.setDescription(`${config.symbols.ERROR} ${config.messages.SERVER_NOT_WHITELISTED}`)
            channel.send({embeds: [WhitelistEmbed]});
          }
        client.guilds.cache.get(guild.id).leave();
      } else { return }
    });

  });

}, 1000 * 3);
```